# Extract country name from rss feed in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I need to extract country names from RSS description field and put this in search on twitter using Yahoo Pipes. So what I need to do first is to extract country name from RSS description. What are the options ? Regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too basic. It would be better to ask more specific questions here with the step where you are stuck. But anyway, here's an outline of the big steps:

1. Use the **Fetch Feed** to get the RSS
2. Copy the *description* field to *country* using the **Rename** operator with *Copy As* option
3. Extract the country name from the description using a **Regex**, by replacing `PREFIX (PATTERN) POSTFIX` with `$1`, where the `PATTERN` should match the country. This way the entire field will be replaced with only the country, getting rid of other text in the same field

Here's an [example pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=5187d6abb53b41506f51ff87afad5dd8) that might be useful for you.